# What is the Big-O analysis of my recursive function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, big-o

Preparing for technical interviews, I solved a practice problem with a recursive solution.

**What is the runtime complexity of a recursive function such as this?** I am more concerned with the explanation rather than the answer.

From my analysis- the number of operations is going to be half of n. That is, a string of 10 characters is going to take 5 function calls in the worst case scenario. But I have never seen an O(n/2) runtime. Also, my analysis excludes the call to the helper function `counterpartOf`. Could someone please show me a proper analysis?

> Write a function that accepts a string consisting of brackets ({}) and returns whether it is balanced.

```
function checkBraces(input){
  // start at the center and work outwards, recursively
  var c = input.length / 2;

  if (input.charAt(c) !== counterpartOf(input.charAt(c-1))) {
    var match = false;
    return match;
  } else {
    // if only 2 characters are left, all braces matched
    if (input.length === 2){
      var match = true;
      return match;
    } else {
      input = input.substring(0,c-1) + input.substring(c+1,input.length);
      return checkBraces(input);
    }
  }
  return match;
}

function counterpartOf(brace){
  closing = ['}', ')', ']'];
  opening = ['{', '(', '['];
  var i = opening.indexOf(brace);
  var counterpart = closing[i];
  return counterpart;
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that if there 2 characters left then string is balanced? If you have string "({}}" then on last iteration you will have "(}" string and initial string is not balanced. Or maybe i am missing something?

Comment: methods like indexOf() have a cost too, they are not constant time. It needs to iterate over the input to find the index. This problem can't be solved without checking every item in the input of length n, so at very best it could be solved with n time.

Comment: @Yevgeniy: If there are only 2 characters left those 2 characters have already passed the false check in the IF statement. Thus, they are matching, and they are the last two characters.

Comment: Then you do not need this check at all.

Comment: @Yevgeniy How else would I end the recursive statement if the input was a valid pair of braces? Don't I need to return some sort of 'success' signal? Having said that, you and Lajos Veres are correct that this algorithm is not accurate. The valid input ```()[]{}(([])){[()][]}``` returns false. My algorithm only works for nested inputs.

Comment: You are right, I can see now why do you need this check. 
"My algorithm only works for nested inputs." - well, yes :). You provided nested input in your example so i assumed that you have only this kind of input.

Comment: What about test cases like `(){}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are irrelevant, this is why you won't see /2, *2 or anything similar.

Details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant

O(k*g) = O(g) if k is non zero.

Otherwise as Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets mentioned your algorithm is not accurate. But apart from his comment I think there are other problems as well.

Usually for similar tasks, they use push down automata's. There is some theoretical background about the issue: http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/texts/theoryOfComputation/7.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your response, Lajos. Does that mean my function runs O(n) time? Because the number of operations is directly proportional to the size of n?

Answer (score 1):

Complexity of your function will be `O(n)` only in case if javascript `substring` function takes constant time. If complexity of `substring` function is `O(k)` where `k` is length of substring then complexity of your function will be `O(n^2)`. You need to check implementation of javascript `substring` function to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of off topic, and not sure if you were required to use recursion, but I think there's a far more efficient way to get the result:

```
function checkBraces( input )
{
   // if the string is an odd number of characters, return immediately.
   if( input.length % 2 !== 0 ) return false; 

   // split the string in half
   var c = input.length / 2;
   var r = input.substr( c );
   var l = input.substr( 0, c );

   // take the left side, reverse it, and swap each left bracket character with it's counterpart
   l = l.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/\{|\(|\[/g, counterpartOf );

   // strings should match
   return r == l;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty cool, thanks! I was not required to use recursion, it was just the most efficient solution I could come up with on a whiteboard. Does the ```replace``` call make your solution O(1)? Or is it faster because it doesn't fill the stack with function calls?